# SSO: Rails app as IDP and Salesforce as Service Provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am working on SSO and trying to make my existing Rails application as the identity provider and Salesforce as the service provider. I have tried saml_idp gem but no luck with it. I am open to implementing any strategy like SAML, Token based authentication, OpenID connect but I am not getting any proper tutorial on how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: Try `ruby-saml` gem https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml.
This example can guide you https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example

Comment: hi @PraveshKhatri, the example provided by you is a Rails app as a service provider rather than IdP.